# Using a bridge even if Tor isn't blocked

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, bridge, internet-service-provider

By using a good bridge, it is more difficult for your ISP to detect that you are using Tor which can slightly improve your anonymity. I know it can slow down your connection speed, but with the benefit mentioned above, should you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to protect your communication from your ISP, the best practice would be to use Tor over VPN.

A VPN establishes an encrypted tunnel between your device and the VPN server, concealing your true IP address and your activities from your ISP and any hackers or malicious individuals who might be monitoring the network.

Using Tor with a VPN gives you an extra layer of privacy because the VPN encryption prevents the Tor entry node (the Tor server where you enter the hidden network) from seeing your IP address. A compromised Tor entry node is one common way for an attacker to try to break Tor’s anonymity. The VPN will encrypt some Internet traffic that Tor does not support, like ICMP traffic. It also prevents your ISP from knowing you are connecting to Tor.

However, there are also disadvantages of using Tor over VPN. While many VPNs support both TCP and UDP traffic, Tor only supports TCP. You must also use a VPN service you trust because the VPN server will be able to see your true IP address. VPN trust means using a reputable VPN service that does not keep logs of your activity and does not serve ads or malware. It’s also important to know what a VPN can and cannot protect against.

If you would like to learn more about this topic, here are some references:

- https://cybernews.com/what-is-vpn/tor-over-vpn/
- https://protonvpn.com/blog/tor-vpn/
- https://surfshark.com/blog/tor-over-vpn
- https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/onion-over-vpn/

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the info!

Comment: Glad to hear that, you're welcome! =)